# How to mass-produce a electronic system assembled by me?

Tags: arduino, prototyping, system, production

"*Practically speaking*", given I developed a electronic system (in my case with the [Arduino](http://arduino.cc/) board), what are next steps to make in order to produce and market that system (in my case, regardless of licenses since those seems to be OK for my Arduino project)? *For example*, who should I contact to mass-produce a electronic system? What type of relationships should I start? What look for and what to care?

Note: I ask that since my [previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/64280/what-make-now-that-i-have-implemented-a-working-prototype-of-my-system).

Comment: Not sure that this question is a good fit here, since it isn't an engineering question _pe se_

Comment: @angelatlarge - Where I should post this question? I posted here because I thought that some engineer could know about this matter.

Comment: As I stated in a comment or answer to your previous question: you must decide on the volume (numer of units) you want to optimize for. Planning for 10's of units a year is totally different from planning for 1000's/y. And the upfront expense is very different!

Comment: @angelatlarge - I'm entirely in favor of questions about the approach one can take to producing a device. Engineering for production, and production engineering are very useful skills, which can interact closely with electrical (and mechanical!) engineering. If it's not explicitly on-topic, it's certainly an essential adjunct.

Comment: @Wouter van Ooijen - OK, I understand. But, *for example*, what kind of company should I contact in order to plan the production? What type of relationships should I start?

Comment: Call Foxconn. If your volume is high enough they will do everything for you from ordering parts to putting your name on it and shipping it to your customers. Selling less than 1,000,000 units per year? Then you need a different answer...

Comment: @Backo, you need to pick a number. Any number, that you think you could sell in a reasonable amount of time. That's step 1.

Comment: I would suggest looking at a few of the recent write-ups on Hackaday from people who've run kickstarters and found out just how much is involved after you've "sold" your idea. There is also some stuff on Dangerous Prototypes about assembly etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I do this for a living: design, prototype and take electronics to manufacture.

You need an electronics assembler / manufacturer. An example is http://www.asteelflash.com/ (no affiliation, but I've worked with them). Find a number of assemblers, bring them your design and ask them to quote for it. They will in turn ask you a number of questions, such as "How many?" and "Do you have funding for this?", before getting to technical questions related to testing and assembly. The smaller ones will let you have a little tour of the factory once they think you're a serious customer.

Asteelflash are probably suitable for the 250-10,000 unit range of production. There are smaller companies that will do smaller runs, usually a few guys in an industrial park in some corner of a city. You can have them hand-assemble for you, but the per-unit cost is quite high.

You need to work out a business plan as well, although that's beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: Would I be right in thinking CE UL ROHS and WEEE etc are also beyond the scope of this site?